# How can I determine the height of a building by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Suppose, I want to determine the total height of a building where the first ten floors of a building: 15 feet/floor, the second ten floors: 12 feet/floor, the rest of the upper floors: 10 feet/floor. if the number of the total floors is 40, then how can I determine the total height of that building by using javascript.

Comment: How would you do it with a pencil and a piece of paper?

Comment: At first, I will calculate the first 10 floors' height. After that, I will calculate the second 10 floors' height. Then the rest of the upper floors. At last, I will combine all these three values. But I don't know how to implement this in JavaScript. @Pointy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to write a function that encapsulates the logic you described. Something like:

```js
function buildingHeight(floors) {
  const num15s = Math.min(10, floors),
    num12s = Math.max(Math.min(20, floors) - 10, 0),
    num10s = Math.max(floors - 20, 0);

  return num15s * 15 + num12s * 12 + num10s * 10;
}

console.log(0, buildingHeight(0));
console.log(8, buildingHeight(8));
console.log(16, buildingHeight(16));
console.log(24, buildingHeight(24));
console.log(100, buildingHeight(100));
console.log(12345678, buildingHeight(12345678));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple math.

```
const firstTenBlocks = 10 * 15
const secondTenBlocks = 10 * 12
const restBlocks = (40 - 20) * 10

const totalHeight = firstTenBlocks + secondTenBlocks + restBlocks
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new in this field. But we can do that when the floor number is constant . My question is how can I do that by using a function where I can give random value of floor number and the result will come out.